# How do I export a filtered table to CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

controller code

```
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @courses.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

Link code

```
<%= link_to "Export Course", courses_path(format: :csv) %>
```

model code

```
def self.to_csv
        CSV.generatezz do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |product|
                csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
            end
        end
    end
```

With that code, I can properly export a csv file that contains every course in the database. I want to set it up where I can export only the information of one course. If possible i'd like to use a variable(like a url parameter) as I have other tables I want to iterate over with the same id that would let me get one course to the csv.

The model code is a class method, which annoyingly enough won't work for an instance of that class, so I can't, in the controller, go `@courses = Course.find(params[:course_id].to_i)` and then `send_data @courses.to_csv`, as it acts as if its an entirely new thing.

Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What if you made an instance method:

```rb
def to_csv
  CSV.generatezz do |csv|
     csv << column_names
     csv << attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end
```

I dont know what `column_names` is here, maybe another method you made? Anyhow, you should be able to call that in your controller after you set the **@course** variable with `@course = Course.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Thanks, this made it work. last time i tried this method i was simply using the wrong variables to input data to the file

Comment: feel free to accept the answer :pray: